# input textfield which detects input text event is not working why showing error 1119?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am New to coding,
I was going through a tutorial and now i get an error in actionscript 3.0,
I was trying to make a text Field which detects text input event and shows it in it,

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type Function.
```

The script file links a movie clip with input text fields
The symbol is named type

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.TextEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class text extends MovieClip
{
    function type()
{
    addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, updateOutput);
}
    function updateOutput(event:TextEvent):void
    {
    var pressedKey:String = event.text;
    type.text = "You typed: " + pressedKey;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line :

```
type.text = "You typed: " + pressedKey;
```

the word 'type' in that line is referring to the function you have created called type. You are trying to set a property called text on that function and it doesn't have that property so you're getting an error.

type should be changed to a reference to the text field you're trying to update.

Comment: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: texts.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method texts.
1120: Access of undefined property texts.

Ok solved the problem ^ but when i add child from main class it gives these errors
instance name of textfield is texts

Comment: I'd need some more information to help you with that, might be best to create another question with your code and exactly what you're trying to do and how.